# Add a character to a blank textfield

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm new to xcode and am stuck on this one action.
I'm trying to add a "Negative" sign or "-" to a field when a button is clicked.

The following code works when someone enters a number into the field... it will add or remove a negative sign to it.

However, if the field is blank and you click on the button it throws an error.

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)fPosNeg:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *str = [userFahrenheit.text mutableCopy];
    char iChar = [str characterAtIndex:0];
    if (iChar == '-') {
        userFahrenheit.text = [userFahrenheit.text substringFromIndex:1];
    } else if (iChar != '-') {
        [str insertString:@"-" atIndex:0];
        userFahrenheit.text = str;
    } else {
        userFahrenheit.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-"];
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a check before calling  this -> [str characterAtIndex:0];

check will be

```
     if(![str isEqualToString:@""]) // so that if string is blank, you cant access its character at index 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"-Test"];
char test = [str characterAtIndex:0];
NSMutableString *strFinal;
if (test  == '-') {
    strFinal = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[str substringFromIndex:1]];
}
else if (test != '-') {
    [str insertString:@"-" atIndex:0];
    strFinal=str;
}
else {
    strFinal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-"];
}
NSLog(@"%@",strFinal);
```

You can also use this.

I think it's solve your problem.